# What is the simplest proof of Euler formula in 3d geometry

Tags: geometry

I arrived at this question when I was thinking whether V+F-E=2 is applicable for a sphere or not.
A little help is required, please send a solution.

Comment: On a sphere it's the same as in the plane, by using "punch a hole and spread the rest out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am responding to the title question, which differs from the question in the body of the post.)

David Eppstein maintains a page that now lists 20 different proofs of Euler's formula: [link here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/euler/).
His own favorite is "interdigitating trees."
After some observations about the dual
graph, it comes down to observing that a tree on $n$ nodes has $n-1$ edges.

---

[image: InterTrees]